# How do I splice multiple (more than two) wires in-line?

Tags: wiring

When I look at many wiring diagrams, like this one:

[image] 
([source](http://www.amb.org/audio/beta22/audio4.png)),

I see wires which need to be connected to multiple points. This suggests that the wire will require multiple three-way splices in order to connect to all the right places. How is this done? I found 3-way heatshrink adapters (like this one: http://www.genuinedealz.com/3-way-wire-splice-butt-connector-w-adhesive-heat-shrink-12-10-awg), but that doesn't seem like an elegant solution. What is the correct approach here?

Comment: related thread: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/115298 .  Welcome to EE.SE, by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a few of these: -

[image]

See [this](http://www.evilution.co.uk/info/splicing_into_wires.htm) website for detail.

Or one of these: -

[image]

See [this](http://www.colorado.edu/physics/EducationIssues/podolefsky/electric_motorcycle_howto_wiring.html) website for detail.

Or one of these: -

[image]

See [this](http://www.brancekrachy.com/82-b1-scotchcast-splicing-kit-p-11881.html) website for detail.

Answer (score 4):

The correct approach is to plan the wiring so that no more than two wires need to be connected to any terminal.

That's almost always possible and when it isn't - in the case of a star ground for instance - a proper terminal board with solder turret terminals, not wire splices, should be used to connect all the wires to the same point.

Here are a couple of examples:

[image]

[image]